# How to reset MySQL performance reports?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I'm trying to use the MySQL performance reports to try and find what is bottlenecking my read and write performance under special situations and It's cluttered up with loads of old statistics regarding other queries to my tables.

I want to clear all the performance data so I can get a fresh look.

The `Clear Event Tables` button doesn't actually seem to clear anything.

How do I do this?

Comment: My opinion:  Abandon the perf reports.  Turn on the slowlog and chase down a few of the busy queries.

Comment: @RickJames I know what the queries are, I want to use the performance reports to try and determine why they are not faster. I highly doubt that queries under 50ms are going to be showing up in the slow queries log. These are some high volume queries I need to sort out some DB & table optimization for.

Comment: `long_query_time = 0` will find the 50ms queries _and_ let you aggregate them to discover whether they add up to more load on the server than other queries.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you figure out how to turn perf reports into _usable_ info, let us know.

Comment: @RickJames But how does that help? I already know what the query is, I don't need to find which query is slow, I already have it. I need to figure out why it is "slow". My CPU utilization is < 2%, I have no Drive I/O (table and indexes are in RAM), and the RAM usage is nowhere near capacity. The queries are very simple too, just trying to find a record with a unique index.

Comment: Is the `UNIQUE` index the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If not, there is a second step.  Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Are there a lot of connections?  Transactions?  Interference between them?  Other apps on the server with MySQL?

Comment: Windows or not?  InnoDB?

Comment: Does the slowlog say "Rows examined = 1"?  "Lock time" of more than a few microseconds?

Comment: You turn the reports into usable info by sorting them different ways and optimizing the top things. If the top things are already optimized, congratulations. It is not uncommon for there to be lots of atrocious things at the top.

Answer (score 3):

Using MySQL Workbench

- Go to `Performance schema setup`
- Click `Clear Event Tables`
- Refresh Reports page. All events will be cleared

Answer (score -1):

(This does not answer the question as asked.  Instead, it addresses the broader question of "how do I improve query performance".)

Here's a simple-minded way to get useful metrics, even for fast queries:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

The numbers may match the table size or the resultset size.  These are good indications of table scan and some action (eg, sort) on the resultset.

A table scan probably means that no index was being used.  Figuring out why is something that metrics probably can't tell you.  But, sometimes there is a way to find that out:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...
```

This will give you (in newer versions) the "cost" of various options.  This *may* help you understand why one index is used over another.

`optimizer_trace` is another tool.

But nothing will give you any clue that `INDEX(a,b)`, which you don't have, would be better than `INDEX(a)`, which you do have.  And that is one of the main points in [*my index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Here's another example of what is hard to deduce from numbers.  There was a production server with MySQL chewing up 100% of the CPU.  The slowlog pointed to a simple `SELECT` that was being performed a lot.  It had

```
WHERE DATE(indexed_column) = '2011-11-11'
```

Changing that dropped the CPU to a mere 2%:

```
WHERE indexed_column >= '2011-11-11'
  AND indexed_column  < '2011-11-11' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

The table was fully cached in RAM.  (Hence, high CPU, low I/O.)  The query had to do a full table scan, applying the `DATE` function to that indexed column for each row.  After changing the code, the index did what it is supposed to do.

Comment: The reason I am trying to do this is my CPU is being utilized at < 2%, I have no Drive I/O (table & keys are in RAM), and allocated RAM is not capped. There are tons of resources available to be utilized, but the queries still are not as fast I want them to be. There has to be something hanging them up that I can see from the surface.

These are very simple queries. Just trying to find a single record based on a unique index.

Comment: What is the network latency?  Are you doing `SELECT *`?  Or selecting specific columns?  Character set conversions?